# Gradle Error - Duplicate Files copied in APK AndroidManifest.xml

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

I am trying to import a library (Evernote Android-SDK) into Android Studio.  I got gradle to find and download it (It showed up in the External Libraries portion or the Project Explorer).  Then it started to tell me it was creating a duplicate file.

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
   }
   dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.5.+'
   }
}
apply plugin: 'android'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:13.0.+'
    compile 'com.evernote:android-sdk:1.1.+'
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 17
    buildToolsVersion "17.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 16
    }
}
```

This is the set of errors that show up.

```
Gradle: : duplicate files during packaging of APK C:\Users\SSMI\My Projects\AutoNote\AndroidProject\AutoNote\build\apk\AutoNote-debug-unaligned.apk
Gradle: Execution failed for task ':AutoNote:packageDebug'.
    > Duplicate files copied in APK AndroidManifest.xml
    File 1: C:\Users\SSMI\My Projects\AutoNote\AndroidProject\AutoNote\build\libs\AutoNote-debug.ap_
    File 2: C:\Users\SSMI\My Projects\AutoNote\AndroidProject\AutoNote\build\libs\AutoNote-debug.ap_
```

What is the problem here and how can I fix it?

**Answer**
So what I did is put a folder in the project root called libraries.  I moved the evernote sdk library folder into that and named it evernote.

Then I went to file project structure.  I ignored the warning.  I went into modules clicked the + and added the evernote folder.  I then selected my app project module and went to the dependencies tab.  I hit + there (you may have to Alt+Insert if it won't click) and added the module I imported (evernote).

I was then tricked into thinking it didn't work because I forgot to import it in the source files.

Comment: Please check your project structure (File -> Project structure). How is your evernote lib included to your project? It should be add once as a module.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't think that you can reference the Evernote Android SDK through maven with Android Studio. The problem stems from the fact that Android libraries can't be packaged as a simple jar.

The Evernote library was built using the maven-android-plugin which isn't compatible with the Android Studio gradle plugin. This is because the maven plugin uses the [apklib](https://code.google.com/p/maven-android-plugin/wiki/ApkLib) format for redistributing libraries, whereas gradle uses the new [aar](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide#TOC-Differences-between-a-Project-and-a-Library-Project) format. That's why gradle is having trouble merging Evernote's AndroidManifest with your own, resulting in duplicates.

Instead, you'll have to clone the Evernote SDK's source, manually import it into Android Studio, and refer to it that way. Their [readme includes instructions](https://github.com/evernote/evernote-sdk-android#include-the-android-library-project-in-your-intellij-workspace) for doing this with Intellij, which should be the same as Android Studio.

Comment: Thank you for the help.  I did get it working now.  It is really too bad you can't use gradle to pick up the newest version like I was trying to do.  It should be able to work the way I had it.

Comment: I thought I had it working.  So it says it compiled fin but android studio is still showing errors in lines where I reference parts of the evernote api.  Is there another step to do so the code completion works properly?

Comment: There shouldn't be. If you modified your gradle files, you can try resyncing them with your Android Studio project - http://stackoverflow.com/a/17098412/108

Comment: Okay.  It all seems to be working.  I just didn't quite do it properly.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error, and it seems to be caused by having a file with the same name in both jar files. for me, both files had a file named "about.html" in their root directory. After renaming the file, everything worked.

Answer (score -1):

You have added a library jar within contain a Manifest.xml file
You can rename type jar to zip. Then extract zip and remove Manifest.xml file.
After that you can compress folder to zip again. Finally rename type to jar.